# Options for running virtual appliance on boot in Windows

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-server-2008, virtual-machines

I'm working on a software package I'd like to be able to release as a virtual appliance. I'll be exporting the appliance from VirtualBox as a .ovf file. Outside of vmware server, are there any Windows host options that allow me to start the appliance when the host OS boots?

Answer (score 0):

I have only ever used vmware for virtual appliances, but the Wikipedia articles on [Virtual Appliance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_appliance) and [Portable Application Creators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_application_creators) have a few links you might want to check out.

Answer (score 0):

So your distribution method will be a virtual disk correct? Does the app work as a service?

Comment: also is it a windows application?  What license model are you going to use?

Answer (score 0):

How about vmware player?

Answer (score 0):

If the host is running Hyper-V (your appliance would need to be in .vhd format) you have a Automatic Start Action and Stop Action inside each VM's settings including automatically start.